# Linux rename mistake recovery

Tags: linux, rename

I made a small mistake trying to rename some files and folders using the rename command.

I am now in a state where all files and folders start with a . (I mean a dot) which turns up for linux to be the hidden file marker.

I tried to use the mv command on a folder but it seems now that is created lots of cifsXX files (no clue what it is) and the content of the folder is gone. In this case I don't really care cause it is not an important folder so let's not try to fix that.

So, does anybody know some kind of magic trick to roll back to a state where I do not have the . front of all of my files?

I have a bit more that 100 files and folders where I made the mistake so I'd love to find a solutions that is safe and at least semi automated so I don't have to do it for all of those one by one.

Comment: `ls -a` will show the dotfiles. And `mv .dotfile dotfile` will rename it back to its undotted version. (use `mv -i .dotfile dotfile` for extra safety)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through your `.*` files and rename them deleting the dot:

```
for file in .*
do
    mv "$file" "${file#*.}"
done
```

The `${var#*.}` strips everything up to the first dot, so in this case it gets the file name without leading dot.

```
$ d="bbb.cc"
$ echo ${d#*.}
cc

$ d=".cc"
$ echo ${d#*.}
cc
```

Comment: Yeah I tried to mark it earlier but apparently I had to wait a bit. Thanks again!

Comment: I think it needs 15 mins since you asked the question. And you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are fond of `rename` you can use it for your problem.

```
rename . '' .*
```

Note: the second argument is actually the empty string, you need the quotes or the argument will not exist. You also need the `.*` because the normal `*` does not expand to the hidden files.

Alas, that doesn't work because it will try to rename the `.` and `..` special directory entries and it will fail and abort.

This should work instead:

```
for x in .*
do
rename . '' "$x"
done
```

It will fail for the `.` and `..` entries but it will go on.

If you want to do it recursively you can use `find` instead:

```
find . -name ".*" -exec rename . '' {} \;
```

Remember to quote the `".*"` in `find` because you don't want the shell to expand the pattern (`find` will handle it).

Answer (score 0):

you can doit using shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in .*
do
 mv $i  `echo $i | sed 's/\.//g'`  
done
```